# How to use dynamic observable variable names in html files in knockoutjs

Tags: php, jquery, knockout.js

I am using knockjs and I have created dynamic observableArrays in js file.
Ex. `product+productid` which creates a dynamic observableArrays as `product123`.

I want to use this in a data bind foreach loop and want to create this variable dynamically again  in html file.

Something like : `data-bind="foreach: { data: "product"+product.id()()}`

So this `"product"+product.id()()` binding should call my product123() array.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey it worked with `vm['product'+product.id()]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$data` to refer to the current context, and use array notation to index your dynamically-named element.

```js
vm = {
  product: ko.observable('123'),
  product123: ko.observableArray([
    'one', 'two', 'three'
  ])
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach: $data['product'+product()]">
  <div data-bind="text: $data"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this creates variable as required. But the data is empty.
Im sure that the variable has items as I get objects when I console log in js file.

Also tried calling it with model object as `vm.$data['product'+product()]`
Cannot read property 'product123' of undefined.

When I manually use product123, it shows data

Comment: P.S : product variables are created dynamically as well.

`var productName = "product" + product.id;
self[productName] = ko.observableArray([]);`

Comment: What do you mean "the data is empty"? In my snippet, you can see that the data are displayed. You are probably running into a problem with scope/context.

Comment: Empty means it does not give error but does not print anything in html file, where as prints data on console log in js file.
Also if I use this hard coded variable **product123** it works just fine in html file.

[jsfiddlelink](https://jsfiddle.net/prashant_bagare/fnkuqoq5/) I am trying to achieve something like this.

Comment: And when I call it using the model object like `vm.$data['product'+productData.id()]`,
it throws error as:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'product123' of undefined;
Bindings value: foreach: {data: vm.$data['product'+productData.id()], as: 'productInfo' }`

Comment: Don't prefix `$data` with `vm`. It's just `$data`.